# delegate declaration for methods with different return values and arguments

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

base on msdn pages, when we declare a delegate we do need to specify return value and also argument of the method that would be called via delegate.

my question:

let's say I have a method as:

`public int MethodA(bool bValue)` and also `void MethodB(int iValue)`

Do I need to declare two different delegates here for each method or I can do it using one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to declare two different delegates here for each method or I can do it using one?

Since these methods have completely different signatures, you need different delegates.  However, you can use the built-in [`Func<bool, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) and [`Action<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegates instead of declaring your own delegate types.

For example, you could use:

```
Func<bool,int> delegateA = this.MethodA;

Action<int> delegateB = this.MethodB;
// or:  Action<int> delegateB = new Action<int>(this.MethodB);
```

Comment: Hi Reed, would you show me an example? I'm new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got some ideas. I'm assuming this a good article to study in this regard. Would you please confirm it?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465122.aspx

Comment: @amitkohan I would actually recommend this instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The point of declaring delegates in the first place is so that you could call a method without seeing its declaration. That is why you need a different delegate type  for each function signature that you are planning to call indirectly through a delegate.

Comment: as you said "calling a method without seeing its declaration". That sounds very interesting but the msdn page I'm reading says we must declare number/type of argument(s) and also return type of method. So how does it work?  I'm still not clear about whole delegate thing

Comment: @amitkohan Declaring a delegate is not the same as declaring a method. By declaring a delegate you specify what methods can be passed for that delegate without declaring these methods, only their signature (parameter types + the return type).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining a separate method and then using a delegate variable to point to it, you can shorten the code using an anonymous method.

```
   class Program{
   delegate void MethodsDelegate(string Message);
   static void Main(string[] args){
   MethodsDelegate method = delegate(string Message){
   Console.WriteLine(Message);
    };
   //---call the delegated method---
 method("Using anonymous method.");
 Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to show me this snippet but I'm not following the method we have here. What is its return value? I guess its argument is string so its return value could be void?

Comment: @amitkohan because it's return value is void you should note that no value is returned from the anonymous method.